# Android Room - Get all items where instance of

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a room database that contains sealed class items.

```
sealed class Object {
    data class Type1() : Object()
    data class Type2() : Object()
    data class Type3() : Object()
}
```

I would like to query the DB to fetch all items of type Type1 for example.

```
@Dao
interface ObjectDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE INSTANCEOF Type1")
    fun getAllType1(): List<Object.Type1>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE INSTANCEOF Type1")
    fun getAllType2(): List<Object.Type2>
}
```

These are examples of a queries I would like to do. Is there anything similar to this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every row in a table has the same set of columns, so this concept doesn't really make sense. I suppose you could create your table so it has columns that correspond with all the possible fields of the three subtypes, making the unique fields nullable, plus one more column with an enum to define which subtype it is. Then you could make requests based on that enum in your WHERE clause. Depending on what you're trying to do, three separate tables may be the more sensible choice.

Comment: Yes this seems confusing, but you said that you already have a database that contains the sealed class items? Can you post some code showing how you achieved adding them?

Comment: You guys are right, I don't think it's possible.... I didn't run the app before posting this question so that's my bad.